# Colorbox query string href, adding dynamic ID?

Tags: jquery, url, hash, href, colorbox

I have coded colorbox so that I can open the first image on the page within a colorbox using the url http://example.com?open=true. I'd like to add a tag using the id attached to a colorbox link in order to open a specific image within a colorbox (not just the first image on the page). The URL should look like this: http://example.com?id=12345?open=true

I know this is probably a piece of cake for most of you, so please help me, I'm trying to learn.

This is colorbox code I am currently using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var
    vars = [],
    hash,
    hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    $("a[rel='example1']").colorbox({open:vars['open'] == 'true' ? true : false});});
```

I don't know much jquery at all, but I'm fairly certain there is an easy way to add an ID to the auto-open URL? The link id's are given automatically through Wordpress so there is no way I can input each id into the jquery by hand.

Here's the code for the image links:

```
<a href="/images/exampleimage.jpg" rel="example1" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
<img src="images/exampleimagethumbnail.jpg" border="0"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the id in vars['id'] so why not just do:

```
 $("a[id="+vars['id']+"]").colorbox({open:vars['open'] == 'true' ? true : false})
```